# HTML5 Voice Recognition, wait til user answered

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition

I'm playing arround with the HTML5 voice recognition.

Currently I have a function like this:

```
doSomething() {
  listen("name");
  console.log("done");
}
```

The "listen" Function works currently like this:

```
recognition =  new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.lang = "de-DE";
recognition.continuous = false;
//recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    result = event.results[event.resultIndex];

    confidence = result[0].confidence;
    result = result[0].transcript.trim();
};

//TODO: remove old results, work with results

recognition.start();
```

What is happening is that Chrome asks for the microphone access and directly does the console.log.
What I want is for the console.log to wait until the speech recognition is done. Like this:

1. Chrome asks for mic access
2. User says something
3. Something is done with what the user said
4. the console.log and everything that follows will be executed.

How can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript programming is [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). The code is not a sequence of statements to execute, but just a description of events to handle and reactions on them.

If you want to perform some action on speech recognized, you need to put it into even handler, in your case:

```
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    result = event.results[event.resultIndex];

    confidence = result[0].confidence;
    result = result[0].transcript.trim();
    console.log("done")
};
```

You can access variables inside handler function and do more complex things.

There are many explanations of event-driven programming on the web, but the most complete one is Chapter 17 Handling Events of [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do)